# How can I combine my MacBook's hard drive partitions?

Tags: macos, partition, filesystem

I have a MacBook Air running Big Sur with a 256GB hard drive that is formatted like this:

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

[image: pic 3]

Because of this, I have extremely limited storage space to work with, even though I never set it up this way and don't care for redundant drive.

I have ample iCloud storage for backups. How can this be fixed, preferably by condensing to one volume?

Comment: You seem have a 128g disk rather than 256g. Can you add at your question the results of this 2 terminal commands : `diskutil list` and `diskutil ap list` ?

Comment: You are right, add as an answer and I’ll upvote

Comment: No problem, but you have 2  useless data volumes. And the diskutil result can help for suppress them. You can edit your question and add informations.

Comment: @Jean_JD You may find my answer here useful when trying to determine which one is the right one to delete: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413403/safe-to-delete-old-macintosh-hd-data-partition/413433#413433

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleteing the redundant partitions?
Click "Partition" icon on the top, then select the partition that you don't want and click the "-" on the bottom.